# How to add a custom input field in Admin Product page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How to add custom input field in Product image form using hooks.I am trying to add a new check box in product image form but i do not know how to create it by using modules as well as i am not able to override core product page template.I am createing directory structure inside themes/classic/module/module_name/.....

If some can write the main module php file of Prestashop 1.7 I am very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class youmodule extends Module
{
    protected $config_form = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'youmodule';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('youmodule');
        $this->description = $this->l('youmodule');

        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('header') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }


    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params)
    {
        $id_product = Tools::getValue('id_product');

        //YOURCODE

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'yourvariable' => $yourvariabl
        ));
        return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/admin/product.tpl');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we save the data that you have created the field in tpl file.